# Numpy: quickest way to check if all elements in an array have the same sign?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking for an optimized or cute way of checking if all the elements of an array have the same sign (strictly).

I've been thinking about doing:

```
N.all(my_array*my_array[0]>0)
```

as it would check if all the elements have the same sign as the first one, and so the same sign but it doesn't seem cute or elegant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like a waste to multiply the whole array. Just look at the sign of the first element and use that, I'd say:

```
N.all(my_array > 0) if my_array[0] > 0 else N.all(my_array < 0)
```

Comment: Just to throw an edge case in, you missed if all of the elements are `0` (though this is a trivial case). In this case it would return `False` although they technically all have the same sign.

Comment: I interpreted his "_strictly_" the same sign as to mean that everything had to be strictly positive or strictly negative, as his code does as well

Comment: Yeah this solution will probably work fine. I just brought that up because if you look at [`numpy.sign`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) they consider `{-1, 0, 1}`.

Comment: Note that this solution still creates a temporary array of boolean values, before iterating this temporary array again to look for the signs. Use `numba`, `cython` or `weave`, if you _really_ want the quickest solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
len(N.unique(N.sign(a)))==1
```

Comment: That still seems a bit inefficient. `numpy.sign` is `O(N)` and so is `numpy.unique` so this is a `O(N^2)` solution. @RemcoGerlich's solution is `O(N)`.

Comment: You are correct. What I meant is that this has to iterate the entire array twice, instead of just once. I know there is no such thing, but it is like a `O(2N)` solution instead of `O(N)`

Comment: I don't know if you tested this code but it doesn't do what you think it does. First, `np.all` takes an array_like argument, and generators are not array like. Try `np.all(1 == 0 for i in range(10))`. You could deal with this by using the built in `all` or by using a list comprehension instead of a generator expression, but you code still would not work. You're testing whether each element is equal to the first, not if their signs are the same. I think maybe you meant to use an `np.sign` somewhere and forgot. Moral of the story, always test your code.

Comment: You still have the issue of the generator expression. Once you fix that, the timing will be pretty different.

Comment: @BiRico Oh my mistake it is actually `N.sign(my_array[0])==N.sign(i)` instead of `my_array[0]==my_array[i]`. Modified my code. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @BiRico, True the timing totally changed. Removed the method as it was twice complex than the given ones. Thanks

Comment: `unique` is actually `O(n log n)`, as it uses sorting to spot the repeated items.